# What can cause ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid on a field with no uniqueness constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, unique

I have a `copy` method that duplicates an object, and then changes some of it's attributes.  When saving this, it gives me an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` error on `Name`.  However, the name attribute does not have a uniqueness constraint, so this should not be failing.

Furthermore, the name HAS been changed so it is unique, and debugging the method indicates this is the case.  How can I be getting this error on a field that doesn't have a uniqueness constraint, and IS unique?

I've seen a bunch of questions about this related to RSpec, but this is not in a testing environment, so it's not a DB problem.

I realize I haven't posted code - I'm looking for general answers on what could possibly cause something like this.

Comment: Anything in the errors? I mean, that's kind of the first place to look.

Comment: Could it be possible that the ID of the duplicate object isn't changed?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to pinpoint actual problem if you could show your code and also Rails version. But if you are looking for general answer, the general answer is that `RecordInvalid` is raised by bang methods, mainly `save!` and `validate!` and other methods that calls those two underneath like `create!`, `update!`. This exception is raised by those methods when validation fails. And validation can fail from million of reasons that depends on your validation setup.

This exception can also be raised when those methods are called on invalid associated records.

I also think that validation may fail when you defined your own validation and return false.